# Add Class While Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to use AddClass in jQuery to add a class while a page and the assets are loading?

For example you could add a class of loading to the body tag.

You can't use the DOM ready function can you?

Comment: why not just give it the class in your html and then use `.removeClass` when the document is done loading?

Comment: That's a good idea. So just add a class of loading and then using the DOM ready function to remove the class?

Comment: yeah, either the document ready event or window load event, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting my comment as an answer so this question can be marked as answered...

Set the loading class in the html and then use `.removeClass` to remove it once the document has finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

This may give you some ideas of how to go about doing this.

https://plus.google.com/116910304844117268718/posts/UkaymyuTzaF

What I usually do is setup a  attribute and then have JS turn it off when all the assets are ready. In CSS then I define a loading animation on areas of the body where I want them to appear.